# .htaccess RewriteRule to convert query-type URL structure to directory-type URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to convert the below url:

```
/letters.php?q=test&d=789&t=2
```

to:

```
/test/789/2
```

I tried something as below, but it did not work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /letters.php?q=$1&d=$2&t=$3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your title and question body ask for opposite things. Please adjust one of them.

Comment: Yes, I want to change the title. How can I do?

Comment: Figured to changed the title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to break up the RewriteRule extract each part of the uri i.e. test, 789 and 2; like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /letters.php?q=$1&d=$2&t=$3 [NC]
```

There is a good article on [.htaccess tip and tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) that shows how rewrite rules work.

Comment: @Fun if this answer solve your problem, do not forget to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/182741).

Comment: If you're going to be doing redirects for more than one page (ex: letters.php, words.php, etc) consider putting in a constant unique part to the URL like `^letters/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$...`.