# .htaccess RewriteRule for directory based with two parameters

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect my webpage in the likes of

```
/dir/script.php?a=123&b=foobar
```

to

```
/123/foobar
```

I've found many answers for questions like this in this site, but none of them work for my problem.
The solution from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/461907/htaccess-rewriterule-to-convert-query-type-url-structure-to-directory-type-url/461910) answer is almost what I need. It works fine for three parameters:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /letters.php?q=$1&d=$2&t=$3 [NC]
```

But if I try to rewrite it for two parameters, as need in my case:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /dir/script.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC]
```

I get a `500 Internal Server Error`. My script is not even executed.
I have tested the regex in Perl and it works fine. There is nothing wrong with it, but Apache somehow refuses to accept it.

I am using the following Apache version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 28 2015 14:05:48
```

Can someone help me get this working?

**EDIT**:

I can't see how this is a duplicate question. The referred question has no mention whatsoever of a dynamic directory based redirection. It mentions named directory redirection, but that is completely different from what I am trying to achieve.

As requested, the log from Apache shows the following:

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to
>   probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase
>   the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

EDIT2:

It was actually re-matching the `/dir/script.php` and redirecting indefinitely.
The solution was to add the flag `END` to the RewriteRule, as specified in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html):

> An alternative flag, [END], can be used to terminate not only the
>   current round of rewrite processing but prevent any subsequent rewrite
>   processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context. This
>   does not apply to new requests resulting from external redirects.

Comment: please share some logs from apache, including error log and mod_rewrite log (level 3). More on how to produce them is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/209270